# Resize div to fit inner content

Tags: html, css

I have an `img` with this css:

```
maxHeight: "80%"
maxWidth: "80%"
```

this is  make the `img` always stay inside the screen. Now I want to put a div around this `img` and some other elements inside that div to make them overlay with the `img`. And I don't know how to make the outside div to fit size with the `img` so other content won't go out of the `img` but the `img` still have to stay inside the screen all the time. Please help! Thank you and sorry about my English!

```
<div class="img-thumb" img-name="@Model[i].TenHinh" img-description="@Model[i].MoTa", img-dim="@Model[i].Width x @Model[i].Height", img-size ="@Model[i].Size">
            <img src="@(domain + "Contents/Imgs/" + @Model[i].MaHinh + @Model[i].Duoi)" />
            <div style="position: relative; display: none;" class="img-preview" >
                <img src="@(domain + "Contents/Imgs/" + @Model[i].MaHinh + @Model[i].Duoi)"/>
                <button style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;"><</button>
                <button style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;">></button>
            </div>
            <div class="img-panel">
                <button type="button" class="btn-Xem" img-code="@Model[i].MaHinh" img-name="@Model[i].TenHinh">Xem</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-Xoa" img-code="@Model[i].MaHinh" img-name="@Model[i].TenHinh">Xóa</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-Sua" img-code="@Model[i].MaHinh">Sửa</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

my div is .img-preview and i want it to fit with the

> img

inside!

Comment: add you html code

Comment: Also you don't need your percent values in quotes.

Comment: i'm setting this css through jquery :) i just need an idea!

Answer (score 0):

set a width and height  to your `div` (here it's **img-thumb**) tag and then set the image `width` and `height` according with it.or else you can set width and height directly to the image .

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }

img{
  max-width:80%;
  max-height:80%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="img-thumb" img-name="@Model[i].TenHinh" img-description="@Model[i].MoTa", img-dim="@Model[i].Width x @Model[i].Height", img-size ="@Model[i].Size">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxhja.jpg" />
            <div style="position: relative; display: none;" class="img-preview" >
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxhja.jpg"/>
                <button style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;"></button>
                <button style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="img-panel">
                <button type="button" class="btn-Xem" img-code="@Model[i].MaHinh" img-name="@Model[i].TenHinh">Xem</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-Xoa" img-code="@Model[i].MaHinh" img-name="@Model[i].TenHinh">Xóa</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-Sua" img-code="@Model[i].MaHinh">Sửa</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i change your div.img-preview display into block to see what happened.
i put some more wrap for the image and for the buttons.
display flex to tidy things up.

and actually i don't see any difficulty here, can you to be more specific about ur question?

```css
.img-preview{
position:relative;
width:100%;
display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.the-image, .buttons{
position:relative}

.buttons{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
width:100%;}

.img-preview img{
width:100%;}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative" class="img-preview" >
<div class="the-image">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5e/Big_Wood%2C_N2.JPG"/>
</div>
 <div class="buttons">
                <button><</button>
                <button>></button>
</div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I've just found the solution, i just have to set the size of the div and then set it's background to the img and center them. Anyway, thank you so much for the quick answer :)